# How to get the position of a node based on the value of a child element

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

In my xml I want specific `menuitems/menuitem` nodes that will be at different arbitrary positions under its parent (I don't want hardcoded position selector).

Is it possible to get the position of a `menuitem` node that has the right value in the name element under it, meaning `menuitems/menuitem/name`. In short: selecting the `menuitem` that has the right `name` value under it.

```
<one>
   <menuitems>
      <menuitem>  <!-- I dont want this one -->
         <name>
           ...
         </name>
      </menuitem>

      <menuitem>   <!-- I want this one at position 2 under <one> -->
         <name>
            ...    <!-- Based one correct name value here --> 
        </name>
      </menuitem>
   </menuitems>

</one>
<two>
  <menuitems>
    <menuitem> <!-- I want this one at position 1 under <two> -->
       <name>
          ...
       </name>
     </menuitem>
   </menuitems>
</two>
```

I can easily find out if one `menuitem` under `menuitems` has the correct `name` value. Like so:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="current()/menuitems/menuitem/name = 'OhYes'"></xsl:value-of>
```

Which will return `true`. But at which position is this `menuitem` amongs other `menuitem` that returned `true`? Selecting under the same parent and at the same level.

I want to avoid this:

```
<xsl:if test="current()/menuitems/menuitem[1]/name = 'OhYes'"> .. </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="current()/menuitems/menuitem[2]/name = 'OhYes'"> .. </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Please post a "working" sample. I.e. one that a query can be crafted to demonstrate what you're asking for?

Comment: Are you really looking for the position? Or are you simply interested in selecting a certain `menuitem` element based on its `name` child element content? If you simply use a path like `//*/menuitems/menuitem[name = 'OhYes']` you select the item elements. If you really want to output the position then use e.g. `<xsl:template match="*/menuitems/menuitem[name = 'OhYes']"><xsl:number/></xsl:template>`. If you want complete code then consider to show us the exact type (i.e. html or xml or text) and content of the result you want to create with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Thats right. Using predicates `/menuitems/menuitem[name = 'OhYes']` is the simple solution to this problem. No need to fiddle with positions :) Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/menuitems/menuitem[name='OhYes']">
   position: <xsl:text/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::menuitem) +1"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:

    
        
            
                
                
           ...
                
            
            
                 -->
                OhYes
            
        
    
    
        
            
                 -->
                OhYes

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   position: 2
   position: 1
```

Comment: Yes, the correct answer is to use predicates  `current()/menuitems/menuitem[name='OhYes']`. Without loop and getting the position is then not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can first seperating out one and two containers using getElementsByTagName. The for each section (one, two) try iterating through all the names by creaing an array using getElementsByTagName, and then checking each element to see if the name is correct. Since each menuitem position corresponds to the name position under each heading (one, two), you can use the .parentNode accessor on each matching name node to return the menuitem node, and the index of the iterator to return its position.

For example, for the XML Code

```
    <one>
   <menuitems>
      <menuitem>  <!-- I dont want this one -->
         <name>
            the incorrect name
         </name>
      </menuitem>
   </menuitems>

   <menuitems>
      <menuitem> <!-- I want this one at position 2 -->
        <name>
           the correct name   <!-- Based one correct name value here --> 
        </name>
      </menuitem>
   </menuitems>
</one>
<two>
  <menuitems>
    <menuitem> <!-- I want this one at position 1 -->
       <name>
          the correct name
       </name>
     </menuitem>
   </menuitems>
</two>
```

The following code alerts the index of the name nodes(and parent menuitem) under the current container (one, two) that cotnain the correct name text in the  tag labeled "the correct name"

```
names = new Array();

// Find the correct position for the menuitem under one
one = document.getElementsByTagName("one")[0];

names = one.getElementsByTagName("name");

for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    if (names[i].innerHTML.search("the correct name") >= 0)
        alert("For one: Correct name found at name node index " + (i+1) + " and its parent menuitem is " + names[i].parentNode);

    // names[i].parentNode is the reference to the menuitem in one that contains the correct name
}   

// Find the correct position for the menuitem under two
two = document.getElementsByTagName("two")[0];

names = two.getElementsByTagName("name");

for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    if (names[i].innerHTML.search("the correct name") >= 0)
        alert("For two: Correct name found at name node index " + (i+1) + " and its parent menuitem is " + names[i].parentNode);

    // names[i].parentNode is the reference to the menuitem in one that contains the correct name

}
```

I have also created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/nMN3j/1/ so you can try it out, and see how it works.

This code will alert that under container "one" a menuitem tagwas found at position 2 that has a correct name sub-tab, but not at position 1, which has an incorrect name sub-tag.

For container "two", the code will alert that a menuitem was found at position 1 that has a correct name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just read the question again. Do you also want the position of the menuitem element under the correct name?